# BehaviorSubject does not deliver value

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

In my code I got two compoents. Component 1 gets Data from an Input, assembles the data via string concatenation and should send it via service to component 2 where the data is processed furthermore. The Problem is that the subscribe method in component 2 is never called.

**Component 1**

```
inputData = ''; // values assigned through template input

submit() {
console.log(this.inputData);
this.service.method(this.inputData) } //method is called when form is submitted
```

**Service**

```
dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
data$ = this.dataSubject.asObservable();

method(data) {
this.dataSubject.next(data); } 
console.log(this.inputData);
```

**Component 2**

```
insertedData = '';

method() {
this.service.data$.subscribe(
data => this.insertedData = data,
error => console.error(error))

console.log('here is the data' + this.insertedData) } method is called when a button from that component is pushed
```

Everything works as expected in Component1 and the Service I can console.log the data that comes from the user input. But when it gets to component2 the data is not there and just the initial value which is ' '(empty string) gets console.logged. That is because subscribe never happens. (I've also tried to just console.log a message there to see if it runs in there but nothing happend so I assume that subscribe never gets executed). On the other hand there  is also no error message which could help me to identify the problem.

Comment: A wild guess: The service is not provided on the same level. As a result each component has an own instance of this service. Please consider providing the service on root level.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm thank you. That solved the problem. For the people that have similar problems: I provided the service in AppComponent and in Component1 and Component2. Delete the provide lines in the components so that it is just provided in AppComponent